# Flutter: ECIES Encrypt/Decrypt

Tags: flutter, dart, security, encryption

I am developing a mobile app that for security has implemented the ECIES scheme for the encryption of information. According to the research I have done, the implementation of ECIES is with KDF2.

I receive the key pairs in the form of a String and these should be used to encrypt or decrypt.

I've searched for information but haven't found much. I have this JavaScript example that does what I need in Flutter.

```
import { encrypt, decrypt } from 'eciesjs';

class ECIES {
    private_key;
    public_key;

    constructor(private_key = '', public_key = '') {
        this.private_key = private_key;
        this.public_key = public_key;
    }

    encrypt(message = '') {
        try {
            if (this.public_key === '') {
                throw new Error("Can't encrypt your data, 'public_key' is not defined.");
            }

            let key_buffered = Buffer.from(this.public_key, 'base64').toString();
            let encrypted = encrypt(key_buffered, message);

            return Buffer.from(encrypted).toString('base64');

        } catch(e) {
            console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    decrypt(data) {
        try {
            if (this.private_key === '') {
                throw new Error("Can't decrypt your data, 'private_key' is not defined.");
            }
            
            let key_buffered = Buffer.from(this.private_key, 'base64').toString();
            let decrypted = decrypt(key_buffered, Buffer.from(data, 'base64'));

            return Buffer.from(decrypted).toString('utf-8');

        } catch(e) {
            console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    getKeyPair() {
        return {
            "private_key": this.private_key,
            "public_key": this.public_key
        };
    }
}


export { ECIES };
```

```
import { ECIES } from './ecies.js';


function test() {
    const private_key = "MDllOTFkYjMxZTNiNTYwMzdkOTVlOGQxYmEyYjQ3NzhjN2M5MGNlODE4YWI0MDE4NWE2YTZiNTQ1MTRmOGM1Zg=="
    const public_key = "MDIzN2E0M2RhYWJiZDJjMjJhZmVjYzE3ZWU3MDkxMDQ1ZDU1YzBkODg2ODIxYmYwMTA0YjEyM2Y0ZmRlZWMyMjc5"
    const ecies = new ECIES(private_key, public_key);

    const message = "Hello world!";

    let msg_encrypted = ecies.encrypt(message);
    console.log(`Encrypted Message: ${msg_encrypted}`);

    let msg_decrypted = ecies.decrypt(msg_encrypted);
    console.log(`Decrypted Message: ${msg_decrypted}`);

    const data = "BD2NPMycdxfE2hJB5jyG6ozs7MHOA0hQrsrEeq5hnLs9PkZmNQE46BAzrO2dUZ0ecKsT2rB6PZo6jzIEU2b0kimhyV29eE6y0E4" +
        "hVbdq14RwVXjnAhSODN8ZC5RBxsjp31ivqH0zAKHMpfHRiPkBBPgVr1gPurSvkkNMknXUtYtPBxbQc9IHpIlZe8YQWX105obraACxDOoCHV2" +
        "I1kWUiuxlABI1knO0pD1e9mNwmdgkq5YhJApVKKVX4WUcGrfVHNnvdRTkBXCf";

    let data_dec = ecies.decrypt(data);
    console.log(`Decrypted Message: ${data_dec}`);
}


(() => {
    test();
})();
```

Comment: Your JS code above is just calling eciesjs, the source code of which is available here: https://github.com/ecies/js/tree/master/src Since you have working test vectors and source code in a different language it should be easy to implement and test in Dart. All the necessary primitives are available in the pointycastle package. Break the problem down it its component parts and test each bit with your test vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JavaScript code](https://github.com/ecies/js) belongs to a [suite](https://github.com/ecies) that implements compatible ECIES codes for various platforms, including a [Java code](https://github.com/ecies/java) using the BouncyCastle library.

For Dart there is a BouncyCastle port, namely PointyCastle. Therefore the Java implementation can be used as a template for the Dart implementation.

Regarding the encryption the following steps are necessary:

1. Create ephemeral key pair
2. Import public key of receiver
3. Get full point to ECDH shared secret, derive AES key via HKDF
4. Encrypt via AES-256, GCM
5. Concatenate (ephemeral public key|nonce|tag|ciphertext) and Base64 encode

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';

...

var rnd = getSecureRandom();
var domainParams = ECDomainParameters("secp256k1");

String encrypt(var rawPubKeyCompUncomp, var plaintext){

  // 1. Create ephemeral key pair
  var ephKeyPair = (KeyGenerator("EC")..init(ParametersWithRandom(ECKeyGeneratorParameters(domainParams), rnd))).generateKeyPair();

  // 2. Import public key of receiver
  var ecPoint = domainParams.curve.decodePoint(hex.decode(rawPubKeyCompUncomp));
  var publicKey = ECPublicKey(ecPoint, domainParams);

  // 3. Get full point to ECDH shared secret, derive AES key via HKDF
  var sharedSecretECPointUncomp = (publicKey.Q! * (ephKeyPair.privateKey as ECPrivateKey).d)!.getEncoded(false);
  var ephPublicKeyUncomp = (ephKeyPair.publicKey as ECPublicKey).Q!.getEncoded(false);
  var aesKey = hkdf(ephPublicKeyUncomp, sharedSecretECPointUncomp);

  // 4. Encrypt via AES-256, GCM
  var nonce = rnd.nextBytes(16);
  var ciphertextTag = (GCMBlockCipher(AESEngine())..init(true, AEADParameters(KeyParameter(aesKey), 128, nonce, Uint8List(0)))).process(plaintext);

  // 5. Concatenate (ephemeral public key|nonce|tag|ciphertext), Base64 encode and return
  return base64.encode(ephPublicKeyUncomp + nonce + ciphertextTag.sublist(ciphertextTag.length - 16) + ciphertextTag.sublist(0, ciphertextTag.length - 16));
}

SecureRandom getSecureRandom() {
  List<int> seed = List<int>.generate(32, (_) => Random.secure().nextInt(256));
  return FortunaRandom()..seed(KeyParameter(Uint8List.fromList(seed)));
}

Uint8List hkdf(var ephPublicKeyUnc, var sharedSecretEcPointUnc) {
  var master = Uint8List.fromList(ephPublicKeyUnc + sharedSecretEcPointUnc);
  var aesKey = Uint8List(32);
  (HKDFKeyDerivator(SHA256Digest())..init(HkdfParameters(master, 32, null))).deriveKey(null, 0, aesKey, 0);
  return aesKey;
}
```

Regarding decryption:

1. Import private key
2. Separate ephemeral public key and nonce|tag|ciphertext, import ephemeral public key
3. Get full point to ECDH shared secret, derive AES key via HKDF
4. Decrypt via AES-256, GCM
5. UTF-8 decode

```dart
String decrypt(var rawPrivKeyHex, var encryptedDataB64){

  // 1. Import private key
  var privateKey = ECPrivateKey(BigInt.parse(rawPrivKeyHex, radix: 16), domainParams);

  // 2. Separate ephemeral public key and nonce|tag|ciphertext, import ephemeral public key
  var encryptedData = base64.decode(encryptedDataB64);
  var ephPublicKey = ECPublicKey(domainParams.curve.decodePoint(encryptedData.sublist(0, 65)), domainParams);
  var nonceTagCiphertext = encryptedData.sublist(65);

  // 3. Get full point to ECDH shared secret, derive AES key via HKDF
  var sharedSecretECPointUncomp = (ephPublicKey.Q! * privateKey.d)!.getEncoded(false);
  var ephPublicKeyUncomp = ephPublicKey.Q!.getEncoded(false);
  var aesKey = hkdf(ephPublicKeyUncomp, sharedSecretECPointUncomp);

  // 4. Decrypt via AES-256, GCM
  var nonce = nonceTagCiphertext.sublist(0, 16);
  var ciphertextTag = nonceTagCiphertext.sublist(16 + 16) + nonceTagCiphertext.sublist(16, 16 + 16);
  var plaintext = (GCMBlockCipher(AESEngine())..init(false, AEADParameters(KeyParameter(aesKey), 128, nonce, Uint8List(0)))).process(Uint8List.fromList(ciphertextTag));

  // 5. UTF-8 decode and return
  return utf8.decode(plaintext);
}
```

---

Test 1: Encryption and decryption:

```dart
var rawPubKeyHex = "0237a43daabbd2c22afecc17ee7091045d55c0d886821bf0104b123f4fdeec2279";
var rawPrivKeyHex = "09e91db31e3b56037d95e8d1ba2b4778c7c90ce818ab40185a6a6b54514f8c5f";

var plaintext = utf8.encode("Es genial trabajar con ordenadores. No discuten, lo recuerdan todo y no se beben tu cerveza. -Paul Leary");
var encryptedDataB64 = encrypt(rawPubKeyHex, plaintext);
print(encryptedDataB64);

var decryptedText = decrypt(rawPrivKeyHex, encryptedDataB64);
print(decryptedText); // Es genial trabajar con ordenadores. No discuten, lo recuerdan todo y no se beben tu cerveza. -Paul Leary
```

Test 2: Decryption of JavaScript ciphertext (which proves the compatibility with the JavaScript code):

```dart
var rawPrivKeyHex = "09e91db31e3b56037d95e8d1ba2b4778c7c90ce818ab40185a6a6b54514f8c5f";

var encryptedDataB64 = "BD2NPMycdxfE2hJB5jyG6ozs7MHOA0hQrsrEeq5hnLs9PkZmNQE46BAzrO2dUZ0ecKsT2rB6PZo6jzIEU2b0kimhyV29eE6y0E4hVbdq14RwVXjnAhSODN8ZC5RBxsjp31ivqH0zAKHMpfHRiPkBBPgVr1gPurSvkkNMknXUtYtPBxbQc9IHpIlZe8YQWX105obraACxDOoCHV2I1kWUiuxlABI1knO0pD1e9mNwmdgkq5YhJApVKKVX4WUcGrfVHNnvdRTkBXCf";
var decryptedText = decrypt(rawPrivKeyHex, encryptedDataB64);
print(decryptedText); // Es genial trabajar con ordenadores. No discuten, lo recuerdan todo y no se beben tu cerveza. -Paul Leary
```

---

Be aware that the keys you posted are encoded twice, once hex encoded and then Base64 encoded, e.g. the Base64 decoding of

```
MDllOTFkYjMxZTNiNTYwMzdkOTVlOGQxYmEyYjQ3NzhjN2M5MGNlODE4YWI0MDE4NWE2YTZiNTQ1MTRmOGM1Zg==
```

and subsequent ASCII decoding gives

```
09e91db31e3b56037d95e8d1ba2b4778c7c90ce818ab40185a6a6b54514f8c5f
```

This double encoding is pointless and inefficient. Therefore, in the above example, the Base64 encoding is omitted and the hex encoded key is used directly.

Also note that for GCM the ecies library applies a nonce length of 16 bytes and not the recommended length of 12 bytes. The above code also uses 16 bytes for compatibility with the JavaScript code.